# jQuery: .load image, then fadeIn() fails when clicked twice!

Tags: jquery, image, load, fadein, preload

So I've got this .load setup for an image with a .fadeIn() callback, that works just fine. The problem is if I fire the .load twice in a row on the same image, it doesn't get to the callback!

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
$('#thumbs a').click( function() {
  imageSrc = $(this).attr('href').substring(1)+'.jpg';   // grab src, remove hash, add jpeg extension
  $('#viewer img').fadeOut('fast', function() {     // fade old image out fast, wait until finished before changing src
   $('#viewer img').attr('src', (mediumPath+imageSrc));  // change src to new image
   $('#viewer a').attr('href', imageSrc);
  });
  $('#viewer img').load(function(){        // once image is loaded, fade the img back in
         $('#viewer img').fadeIn('slow');
        });
  return false;
 });
```

And you can try it on my website (in progress) [here](http://www.benjibee.com/). Just click on a thumbnail on the left twice in a row and the loader.gif doesn't go away, i.e. not getting to .fadeIn().

**Note**: *I believe this is only affecting WebKit Browsers(?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your site http://www.benjibee.com/ in Chrome (Webkit-based Browser, as far as I know), and have been unable to replicate the problem. Although it does take a little longer than in Firefox (but that may just be my computer).

A couple of suggestions/observations.

With your `.click()` based interactions, using the format:

```
.click( function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Rest of your Javascript Code here...
} );
```

Will stop an anchor/link from performing as such, and can be evoked at the start of the jQuery processing, rather than waiting for the end to use `return false`.

You may also want to store in a javascript variable the details of the current image/link, and then check against that on subsequent clicks on the Thumbnails - as it stands, if `img1.jpg` is shown, and the thumb for that image is clicked, the current larger image fades out, and then fades back in again with no change. Just a tiny thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate it. I think I shouldn't be pointing people here to the site while I'm actively working on it, hah. I'll work on a local copy for now, so as it stands the page that is up has that bugginess.

As for the return false, I'm aware of the other method, I had those pasted in there because I plan on using jQuery BBQ for hash navigation, but wanted to get rid of them while building other code.